# How do I get the current value of a jquery-ui auto-complete using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to get the value of a jquery-ui autocomplete. Using jquery I can get the value using `$("#PartNum").val()`

Using Selenium `driver.findElement(By.id("PartNum")).getText()` I get an empty string.

This is with Selenium 2.39.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get text from a `value`, you can use `getAttribute`:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("PartNum")).getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: Thanks it's strange because I didn't see the value attribute in Firebug: `<input id="PartNum" class="inPartNum ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" type="text" name="PartNum" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">`

Comment: My understanding is that jQuery sometimes stores `value` in a different place, but you can still access it by querying `value`.

Comment: One other thing is that you may want to delay a bit before looking for the value to give the autocomplete some time if there's some latency with the server (if you're doing autocomplete that way)